# How to upload file from my iphone application to user own dropbox?

Tags: objective-c, ios, api, dropbox

I had created an iphone application witch can generate a pdf file when the user use the application.
how can the user have the option to sent the pdf file to his own dropbox?

I had tryed with dropbox examples: where i can make an api and upload to my own dropbox.
But it's not what i want.

I want my application to do so: when the user generates a pdf file, so the login box of dropbox apear so he can log in and upload the file automaticaly to his own dropbox.

I have google it, but i did't get any examples including this solution.

Please help me if you can.

Comment: Follow this example:[Authenticating iOS](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#ios) Also take a look at the [Dropbox tutorial for developers](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/core)

Comment: I had already tryed it. But no success, as i wrote i my question. Thanks

Comment: You're right, my fault. As the tutorial says, " Make sure you are logged in using the same email address you used to create the app keys." I'm looking for a better solution

Comment: However, at the beginning of the document it reads "Now that you've gotten the SDK building with your project, the next step is to integrate it into your app, allowing users to link their Dropbox accounts to your app" That's the usual behavior to expect, I'm confused now. Maybe you should take a look [here](https://github.com/search?q=dropbox&p=1&ref=searchbar&type=Repositories&l=Objective-C) to see working projects

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this blog post that i think describes what you are looking for.

http://www.drdobbs.com/tools/working-with-dropbox/232600482?pgno=1

Comment: Hi @Djo have you solved this issue with this tutorial or any other? thanks in advance!